# FFTW compile error c++

Tags: c++, compilation, fftw

I have included the header file of fftw3 `#include "fftw-3.3.4/api/fftw3.h"` -same directory as the rest of the header files, but when I try to compile I get an error for all the fftw functions:

```
error: ‘fftwnd_destroy_plan’ was not declared in this scope
```

Do I have to put a declaration in front of each function as opencv uses `"cv::"`? And if so, which is this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to compile some old FFTW 2 example code using FFTW 3. `fftwnd_destroy_plan` was in FFTW 2 but is obsolete in FFTW 3. See the [FFTW 3 documentation regarding upgrading from FFTW 2 to FFTW 3](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Upgrading-from-FFTW-version-2.html), particularly the section on plans:

> FFTW 2 had separate data types `fftw_plan`, `fftwnd_plan`, `rfftw_plan`, and `rfftwnd_plan` for complex and real one- and multi-dimensional transforms, and each type had its own ‘destroy’ function. In FFTW 3, all plans are of type `fftw_plan` and all are destroyed by `fftw_destroy_plan(plan)`.

---

TL;DR: change `fftwnd_destroy_plan` to `fftw_destroy_plan`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the mistake.. now have you any idea how to link -lfftw3f  permanently